# How to get an object style in Illustrator scripting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, graphic-styles

I'm writing a script to automate scene states. I using graphic styles to change appearance. How do I get object's `graphicStyle`? Is there a way to have a collection of objects of chosen style?

Comment: Can't play around in Illustrator right now to give a specific answer. But I'm looking at the Scripting Reference... does the `length` property, or such methods as `getByName` or `index` get you close to what you need? I know that Illustrator scripting can be really frustrating and Adobe's documentation isn't all that helpful :(

Comment: @Brendan I have read documentation and realize that `graphicStyles` (`getByName` and `index`) is returning not `groupItem` as it is said in the documentation, but `graphicStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you make with all objects, but if you wuold select all item with same graphic style you can use **`app.executeMenuCommand('Find Style menu item');`** script after selection active on one object with choosen style.

For example:
choose 1 object and launch this script:

```
app.executeMenuCommand('Find Style menu item');
for(var i=0;i<app.selection.length;i++){
app.selection[i].doSomething;
 }
```

Hope it's work for you.